# Javascript for select specific data value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me blow my out put Java Script, convert to only "Text" Name only, How can do it using JavaScript or Json.

```
var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CourierList));
```

This code out put below:

```
var list = [  
{  
  "Disabled":false,
  "Group":null,
  "Selected":false,
  "Text":" Bob-Ann169$ ",
  "Value":null
},
{  
  "Disabled":false,
  "Group":null,
  "Selected":false,
  "Text":" Brian-Pam4$ ",
  "Value":null
},
{  
  "Disabled":false,
  "Group":null,
  "Selected":false,
  "Text":" Ken-Greer126$ ",
  "Value":null
}];
```

My output should be only below names, please tell me how break to following output

```
Bob-Ann169$,
Brian-Pam4$
Ken-Greer126$
```

Above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a simple list object iteration such as:

```
for(var  i in list){
    alert(list[i].Text);
}
```

See:
**http://jsfiddle.net/wp1wtxa8/**

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(((SelectList)ViewBag.CourierList).ToList().Select(cc=>cc.Text).ToList())) 
    console.log(list);
```

It is more dependent on How you have constructed your SelectList. I think in your case you have constructed using List or string[] so it required to cast in properly.

Comment: Some error comes, $exception {"Cannot convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'"} System.Exception {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}

Comment: same error will come, $exception {"Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'"} System.Exception {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}